# How can i show a 404 error from Apache when .php does not exist

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

I have WP site with redirects setup as follows :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Which works fine for all URLs. But if i access a url like "**/file/does/not/exist.php**" it shows a WP 404 error page. I dont want that request to reach WP, it should show a 404 from apache.

So "**/file/does/not/exist**" should go to **WP 404 page (it does)** but "**/file/does/not/exist.php**" should be a **404 from Apache**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of conflicts with the `!-f` RewriteCond ("not a file"). A missing script is not a file, therefore it satisifies the rewrite condition. You may have to specifically check if the filename contains '.php' and not rewrite to wordpress. But what if someone tries to access some other file extension which should also be a 404?

Comment: You're right. I added another rewrite rule after the first one that specifically checks if the file is .php and doesn't exist, it returns a 404 header. I haven't dealt with other file extensions yet. Any clues?

Comment: You could put all the wordpress-specific rewriteable urls under a /wp prefix in the path, perhaps. Anything without that /wp prefix shouldn't get re-writtn and let the regular handling rules kick in.